# Need overflow:visible on one side and overflow:hidden on bottom side

Tags: css

I would like the end result to look like this: 
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/65978956/Capture.JPG

1. The #logo image is positioned inside the .page div with some text overflowing the div.
2. The #logo image's position has to be relative to the .page div´s position so that it would always be positioned the way it is on the picture.

The problem is, that since I can only get the #logo to overlap when I set its position as absolute the .page div no longer auto-resizes with the content vertically.

The overflow-x and overflow-y values don't allow me to achieve what I am looking for

```
body {
    background-color: beige;
}

.page {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 984px;
    min-height: 800px;
}

#logo {
    background-image: url(../Content/Site_Images/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 444px;
    left: -98px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    width: 381px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

and my view file:

```
<body>
  <section class="Page">
    <figure id="logo"></figure>

    @*--Other omitted sections--*@
    .....
    .....
  </section>
</body>
```

What should I be doing to get the desired effect.

Thanks for helping

EDIT.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ngsEG/1/

See how the content does not resize and the image is displayed correctly. If I add overflow:hidden to the .page section, then the page resizes, but the image overflow is also hidden.

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle example:  http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's unclear what behavior you are expecting. I don't see how having `logo` absolute will cause any issues with veritcal sizing of `page` content. Your title mentions `overflow` questions, but your text mentions nothing about `overflow`. A fiddle like Alex W asked for would be good too, but mainly, a clearer exlpanation of what you expect.

Comment: Added the jsFiddle to my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, with the fiddle you posted, it becomes apparent that your issue has nothing to do with the `absolute` position of the logo. Rather, your `@*--Other omitted sections--*@` and its css was the issue, namely, the `float` on `#MainContent` was not being wrapped by the `.Page` element. Because of what you are trying to do with the logo, I agree, the typical fixes of `overflow: hidden` or `auto` do not work here. However, the old [**clearfix**](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) solution should. So:

```
.Page:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[See the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ngsEG/4/)

Note: if IE7 or less support is needed, see the additional info in the clearfix link above.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.I completely forgot that float breaks the element flow. The .Page:after method worked, but I ended up changing the float:left on the #MainContent to display:block and making it work that way.

Comment: @JoonasL--oh yes, if you don't need to `float` it, don't! That is a much better solution; I just assumed you had the `float` for a reason.